# How to map a function taking two parameters (instead of one)?

Tags: haskell, map-function

I have a Haskell problem and I came up with a solution but I just can't put pen to paper.

Basically I have a function `calc` that takes in an `Int` and returns a `Float`.

```
calc :: Int -> Int -> Float
```

In my function `g` I want to apply this function on an array

```
g :: [Int] -> [Float]
```

Since `calc` takes two `Int` parameters I want to consume two `Int`s (
`x` being the first index of the array and `x+1` being second index). This will keep repeating the function on (index of array) `[1][2], [2][3], [3][4]` etc.

```hs
g :: [Int] -> [Float]
g [] = ""
g (x:xs) = map calc x x+1 

calc :: Int -> Int -> Float 
calc current last = (current - last / last) * 100
```

I've tried to research online on how to use `map` and it basically said like this? Any idea why the code doesn't want to compile and if `x+1` is even a viable?

Comment: There are no arrays here. `[Float]` is a _list_ of floats. And, you don't seem to have “a function that takes in an Int and returns a float”. It's not clear what result you actually want, please add some examples.

Comment: Maybe you need some kind of fold over the list, e.g. `foldr` or `foldl`. From what you wrote it's hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The calc function performs some arithemetic on two inputs. The inputs are recieved from a list current will be at list position [0] and last will be at position [1]. This will loop and store the outputs in a list so it will then use [1][2] and [2][3] and so on untill all the elements in the list have been computed

Comment: Maybe you want something like: `g (x:y:xs) = calc x y : g (y:xs)` and `g _ = []`

Comment: @Lynn that line of thought can be also expressed as `g xs = [calc x y | (x:y:_) <- tails xs]`.

Answer (score 5):

*Unary* map is `map` but *binary* map is `zipWith`. So what's to *zip* together?  The two copies of the same list, shifted by one position one against the other:

```
calc :: Int -> Int -> Float
g :: [Int] -> [Float]
g xs = zipWith calc xs (drop 1 xs)
```

This is all.  The zipping automatically stops when the shorter sequence runs out.

`zipWith foo` applies `foo` to each pair of  arguments, each argument coming from the corresponding list, one element after the other. It could be implemented using `zip` as

```
zipWith foo xs ys  =  map (\ (x,y) -> foo x y) $ zip xs ys
                   =  [ foo x y | (x,y) <- zip xs ys ]
```

but it already does this by itself.

As an illustration, `drop 1 [1,2,3] == [2,3]` and this  means that

```
zipWith calc [1, 2, 3] (drop 1 [1, 2, 3]) ==
zipWith calc [1, 2, 3] 
             [2, 3   ] ==
        [calc 1 
              2, 
            calc 2 
                 3]
```

You wanted to use indices. Indices are practically never used in Haskell with lists.  We instead achieve the same effect by *structural* jiggling, and then when we advance along the two lists one element at a time, each operation is *O(1)* because the next element is already at the top of the advanced list. Whereas with the indices we'd have to traverse the same list from the top anew each time, leading to *O(k)* time per *each one* (`k`th) element, i.e. *quadratic* behavior overall.

---

*update:* taking the zipping approach leads to a possibility of code fusion,

```
g2 xs  =  zipWith calc xs (drop 1 xs)
       =  [calc x y | (x,y) <- zip xs (drop 1 xs)]
       =  [calc x y | (x:y:_) <- tails xs]  -- tails ~= iterate (drop 1)
```

because why build a new structure to house the two consecutive elements when they already appear in a structure ... the *original* list structure.

Interestingly, Common Lisp has this special kind of map, a map on tails, as part of the language. While the regular map is known there as `mapcar`, the map on tails is known there as [`maplist`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) (it's a map on *non-empty* tails, to be precise).

Comment: From my understanding zip creates a list of tuples, I want to create a list of floats

Comment: *`zipWith`* is what I'm using here. :) `zipWith foo` applies `foo` to the two arguments, each coming from the corresponding list.

Comment: Ah I got you thanks! I'm trying to read your code with some understanding, I wanted to ask why are you dropping 1 on line 3?

Comment: `drop 1 [1,2,3] == [2,3]` and that is what we want: then, zipping gets us `zipWith calc [1,2,3] (drop 1 [1,2,3]) == [calc 1 2, calc 2 3]`

Comment: Nice, see my way of thinking was to use the list indexes whereas you just use 2 lists and removed one from the front, this will be something for me to keep in mind in the future :))

Answer (score 0):

<s>I think the best</s> a solution is

```hs
-- Returns the empty list on empty list due to laziness of zip

g xs = uncurry calc `map` zip xs (tail xs)
--     |                  |- this is the list of pairs with indeces: [(1,2), (2,3), (3,4) ...] 
--     |- this converts a two arguments functions on a function with single 2-tuple argument
```

EDIT: @Will Ness solution is actually better.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen inline `map` before. What is the point? To me it harder for a beginner to read than using prefix map as usual, and harder for an expert to read than using `<$>` instead.

Comment: @amalloy infix map to avoid too many parenthesis and not using `<$>` to avoid an operator which might be unkown to OP. Well... honestly It looks clear to me, but probably you are right about infix `map`...